# DateDisplayFormat not changing for Content Control in Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

I have a MS Word template in which I have a datetime Content Control. I am setting the date on a button click after changing the language from UI.

This is what I do...

```
foreach (var cc in dateCCs.Where(cc => cc.ContentControl.Type == Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlDate))
{
  cc.ContentControl.DateDisplayFormat = lng.DateFormat;
  cc.ContentControl.DateDisplayLocale = (Word.WdLanguageID)lng.CorrectionLanguage;
}
```

Now the content control's Locale is changed when I change the language, but the format is not changed. Can anybody help me on this ?

### **UPDATE:**

Here are the answers 
1) Please describe how the(se) content control(s) are created in the Word template (settings); 
*I don't know. They are in the template.*

2) What is lng in your code snippet; 
*lng is a Database Object Mapper containing the above two properties.*

3) Please provide examples of the language and date formatting you start out with and 
*English Language Date Format is d MMMM yyyy and German Language Date Format is d. MMMM yyyy (notice the dot)*

4) what you expect as the end result
*I want the content control to change the date format just like the locale is changed*.

### **UPDATE 2:**

Further findings reveal that this is related to the edit language of Word. Here is the scenario.

1. If my edit Language is Danish. When I try to set the DateDisplayFormat to Deutsch (German), it won't change.
2. If my edit Language is Deutsch. vice versa
3. But if my edit Language is English UK. It works well.

*Is this a bug in MS Word ?*

Comment: You don't' provide enough information to repro and test. 1) Please describe how the(se) content control(s) are created in the Word template (settings); 2) What is `lng` in your code snippet; 3) Please provide examples of the language and date formatting you start out with and 4) what you expect as the end result

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the long date format (with the month spelled out), when you change the locale Word isn't recognizing the content as a valid date. For example, März and March.

So what you need to do is first change the display date to a "neutral" format that's not language-dependent, then change the locale, and then the display data again.

For example:

```
cc.DateDisplayFormat = "d-M-yyyy"
cc.DateDisplayLocale = 2055 'Swiss German
cc.DateDisplayFormat = "d. MMMM yyyy"
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and while debugging the code, I can see that content control simply does not change the date format after executing both the date format lines. Locale is changed though.

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE 2:** as well :)

Comment: @NaveedButt Further to your update, and I'll incorporate this into my Answer later today, when I'm not on a mobile device: set the proofing language of the `cc.Range` - I think it's `LanguageID` and should be the same information as the DisplayLocale.

Comment: I don't exactly get, what you are trying to say here. Can you explain a bit more? I was unable to find `cc.Range`

Comment: I tried to set `cc.ContentControl.Range.LanguageId` but even it did not work... Any other ideas ? I noticed that one of the content control's storage format was text. I tried to change that before setting the format, but it didn't work either :)

Comment: At this point, I'm not following exactly what you've tried. In my code sample, cc is a ContentControl object. It's not clear to me what cc is in your code because you type it as a `var` and you don't show us how dateCCs is derived. And some exact repro steps using languages we might have installed and available (French and German, for example). Is Danish actually installed and activated in Windows and in Office on your machine?